# PJSIP iOS video call implementation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, pjsip

i am a complete newbie in VOIP, i have never study about how this thing work before, but now i have a project that required me to have knowledge about this thing.

So here's the thing, can someone guide me or tell me what should i do about:

how to implement video call in iOS version?

I have been studying this library since last week, the sample it comes with the source code as well as siphon, but i still can't find the correct way to initiate a video call or receive a video call.Like what should i do before i make the call and what should i do after i answer the call.

All the core function are taken from internet.
Here is what i used to initialize Pjsua:

```
// Init pjsua
{
    // Init the config structure
    pjsua_config cfg;
    pjsua_config_default (&cfg);

    cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
    cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
    cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;
    cfg.cb.on_reg_state2 = &on_reg_state2;
    cfg.cb.on_call_media_event = &on_call_media_event;

    // Init the logging config structure
    pjsua_logging_config log_cfg;
    pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
    log_cfg.console_level = 4;

    // Init PJ Media
    pjsua_media_config me_cfg;
    pjsua_media_config_default(&me_cfg);


    // Init the pjsua
    status = pjsua_init(&cfg, &log_cfg, &me_cfg);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_init()", status);

}
```

And here is how i configure my account

```
// Initialization is done, now start pjsua
status = pjsua_start();
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error starting pjsua", status);

// Register the account on local sip server
{
    pjsua_acc_config cfg;

    pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);

    // Account ID
    char sipId[MAX_SIP_ID_LENGTH];
    sprintf(sipId, "sip:%s@%s", sipUser, sipDomain);
    cfg.id = pj_str(sipId);

    // Reg URI
    char regUri[MAX_SIP_REG_URI_LENGTH];
    sprintf(regUri, "sip:%s", sipDomain);
    cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(regUri);

    // Account cred info
    cfg.cred_count = 1;
    cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");
    cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("*");
    cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(sipUser);
    cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
    cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(password);

    //Normal Video Setup For Account
    cfg.vid_in_auto_show = PJ_TRUE;
    cfg.vid_out_auto_transmit = PJ_TRUE;
    cfg.vid_wnd_flags = PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_WND_BORDER | PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_WND_RESIZABLE;
    cfg.vid_cap_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV;
    cfg.vid_rend_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_RENDER_DEV;
    cfg.reg_retry_interval = 300;
    cfg.reg_first_retry_interval = 30;


    status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &_acc_id);

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error adding account", status);
    pjsua_acc_set_online_status(_acc_id, PJ_TRUE);

    pjsua_call_setting_default(&_call_setting);

    _call_setting.aud_cnt = 1;
    _call_setting.vid_cnt = 1;


}
```

Here is how i make my call

```
pj_status_t status;
pj_str_t uri = pj_str(destUri);

status = pjsua_call_make_call(_acc_id, &uri, &(_call_setting), NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error making call", status);
```

Here is how i handle my incoming call

```
    /* Callback called by the library upon receiving incoming call */
static void on_incoming_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_call_id call_id,
                             pjsip_rx_data *rdata)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;
    pjsua_call_setting opt;
    pjsua_call_setting_default(&opt);
    pjsua_vid_preview_param p_param;

pjsua_vid_preview_param_default(&p_param);

p_param.show = PJ_TRUE;


opt.aud_cnt = 1; //number of simultaneous audio call
opt.vid_cnt = 1; // number of simultaneous video call

PJ_UNUSED_ARG(acc_id);
PJ_UNUSED_ARG(rdata);

pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);

PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Incoming call from %.*s!!",
          (int)ci.remote_info.slen,
          ci.remote_info.ptr));
pjsua_call_answer2(call_id, &opt, 200, NULL, NULL);

/* Automatically answer incoming calls with 200/OK */
```

}

Here is how i handle my media state

```
    static void on_call_media_state(pjsua_call_id call_id)
{

pjsua_call_info call_info;

unsigned mi;
pj_bool_t has_error = PJ_FALSE;

pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &call_info);


for (mi=0; mi<call_info.media_cnt; ++mi) {
    printf("MyLogger: looping ");
    on_call_generic_media_state(&call_info, mi, &has_error);

    switch (call_info.media[mi].type) {
        case PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
            printf("MyLogger: case audio ");
            on_call_audio_state(&call_info, mi, &has_error);
            break;
        case PJMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
            printf("MyLogger: case video ");
            on_call_video_state(&call_info, mi, &has_error);

            break;
        default:
            /* Make gcc happy about enum not handled by switch/case */
            printf("MyLogger: default case ");
            break;
    }
}
static void on_call_video_state(pjsua_call_info *ci, unsigned mi,
                            pj_bool_t *has_error)
{
    NSLog(@"windows id : %d",ci->media[mi].stream.vid.win_in);
    NSLog(@"media id : %d",mi);
    if (ci->media_status != PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE)
        return;
    [[XCPjsua sharedXCPjsua] displayWindow:ci->media[mi].stream.vid.win_in];
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(has_error);
}
```

Lastly this is how i display a video window:

```
void displayWindow(pjsua_vid_win_id wid)
{
#if PJSUA_HAS_VIDEO
NSLog(@"windows id : %d",wid);
int i, last;

i = (wid == PJSUA_INVALID_ID) ? 0 : wid;
last = (wid == PJSUA_INVALID_ID) ? PJSUA_MAX_VID_WINS : wid+1;
if(wid == PJSUA_INVALID_ID){
printf("MyLogger: displayWindow failed\n");
}else{
printf("MyLogger: displayWindow success\n");}
for (;i < last; ++i) {
    pjsua_vid_win_info wi;
    pj_status_t myStatus;
    myStatus = pjsua_vid_win_get_info(i, &wi);
    if(myStatus != PJ_SUCCESS) pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, THIS_FILE, myStatus);
    if (myStatus == PJ_SUCCESS) {
        UIView *parent = mainViewController.view;
        UIView *view = (__bridge UIView *)wi.hwnd.info.ios.window;

        if (view) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                /* Add the video window as subview */
                if (![view isDescendantOfView:parent]){
                    [parent addSubview:view];
                }
                if (!wi.is_native) {
                    /* Resize it to fit width */
                    view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, parent.bounds.size.width,
                                             (parent.bounds.size.height *
                                              1.0*parent.bounds.size.width/
                                              view.bounds.size.width));
                    /* Center it horizontally */
                    view.center = CGPointMake(parent.bounds.size.width/2.0,
                                              view.bounds.size.height/2.0);
                } else {
                    /* Preview window, move it to the bottom */
                    view.center = CGPointMake(parent.bounds.size.width/2.0,
                                              parent.bounds.size.height-
                                              view.bounds.size.height/2.0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}


#endif
}
```

When i receive an incoming call, displayWindow(pjsua_vid_win_id wid) will be called, but it always print "MyLogger: displayWindow failed\n" in my console, so i believe i have something missing, but i have no clue what it is.

Please help.

Comment: When you receive incoming call you want to show a view controller and it is called from incoming call merhod. But where this display window is called? Please explain briefly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, after a month of try and error, i had identified that problem comes from codec compatibility and my shallow knowledge about view hierarchy

Comment: Hi Y. J. Leong, I have had a similar problem like this. Sad I did not find this question earlier. I did manage to resolve it, however, adding the final view like you did with `[parent addSubview:view];` fails with `+[GLView superview]: unrecognized selector sent to class` for me. Did you notice any similar errors? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @cybrox i don't really remember whether i had encountered this problem before, but i guess you need to check your parent view, is it null?

Comment: could you please send me the code for video calling. I am stuck on the same. @Y.J.Leong

Comment: @ved what is your problem facing right now?

Comment: Unable to integrate video call through pjsip... Audio call is working fine at my end but unfortunately video is not @Y.J.Leong

Comment: @ved yes, i know you are unable to integrate video call through pjsip, but i want to know what problem is troubling you, for example, no video packets transmission been observed, green window, one side video, or so on. If you can provide some error/warning logs, that is even better

Comment: Can you please send me only method definition of video call. I did not find any code for video call.

Comment: @ved you can just follow this method i wrote"void displayWindow(pjsua_vid_win_id wid)".

You also can try send out reinvite request: pj_status_t  pjsua_call_reinvite2 (pjsua_call_id call_id, const pjsua_call_setting *opt, const pjsua_msg_data *msg_data)

Remember to enable vid_cnt = 1, otherwise you will not receive video stream

And you actually can find the video setting in this URL: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Video_Users_Guide

Comment: We are not able to access  view of video call in this meyhod. Can you please help more?

Comment: Hi Y.J.Leong, I am trying to integrate video call in my pjsip ios app. I got the green window as you mentioned in your comment. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: This is most probably because of the payload length

Comment: on_incoming_call() - is not getting called in iOS. does it mean the sip is not connected ?

Comment: @Y.J.Leong Thank you for your question. This helps many people understand how to implement video calls. But could you please edit your question and explain what you did with the codec issue and view hierarchy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who is having the **green window** of the incoming video but without the video frames, I had experienced the same situation in the past few days. Here is my 2-cents for a possible cause of the issue.

Following the `PJSIP Video User's Guide`, I assumed setting `vid_in_auto_show = PJ_TRUE` would be good enough to auto-show incoming video, while `vid_out_auto_transmit = PJ_TRUE` turned out to be my missing piece. According to the user's guide: *"Setting this to PJ_TRUE will cause video transmission to be started automatically on each outgoing calls and on incoming calls that indicates video support in its offer"*. After setting `vid_out_auto_transmit = PJ_TRUE`, even without setting `vid_in_auto_show = PJ_TRUE`, video would come up shortly after the green window shows up on my side.

And don't forget to make sure `vid_cnt`, `vid_cap_dev`, and `vid_rend_dev` are together properly set before calling `pjsua_acc_add`.

Comment: on_incoming_call() - is not getting called in iOS. does it mean the sip is not connected ?

Comment: @iosdeveloper does the sip account have been successfully registered?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. No sip was not getting registered. I registered that and now it is working.Thank you.